# swing uncaughtexceptionhandler

Tags: swing, exception, jython

I am trying to build a general exception handler for a swing application as described here: http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue081.html

I work in jython (python syntax getting compiled to java and executed). My code looks roughly like this (**updated**):

```
def launcher(func):
    class launcherThread(Runnable):
        def __init__(self):
            super(launcherThread, self).__init__()

        def run(self):
            func()

    #trying to get the name which can be used to instantiate this in java
    cls = ExceptionGroup().getClass()
    fullName = cls.__module__ + '.' + cls.__name__

    System.setProperty("sun.awt.exception.handler", fullName)
    Thread(ExceptionGroup(), launcherThread(), 'Cross ExceptionHandlerThread').start()

class ExceptionGroup(ThreadGroup):
    def __init__(self):
         super(ExceptionGroup, self).__init__("HardenedGroup")

    def uncaughtException(self, thread, exception):
        #make a fancy dialog displaying str(exception)
```

If I test it it works fine however in the production enviornment it failes.
For testing I launch my program in Eclipse (PyDev), the production enviornment is a third party application written in Java, that has a Jython console build in. The application supports adding of custom menu entries, and putting jython scripts on these.

The main difference I see between testing and production enviornment is that in the production enviornment the swing threads are allready started (the third party application utilitizes swing). Does this cause my `ThreadGroup` setting to fail, or is there another reason why this is not working?

How can I get the Involved threads (exceptions ar thrown as a result of buttonActions) to check their defaultException handlers? If (as I am afraid) it should turn out that the third party installed its own handler (all exceptions are written to a log file) how can I make a new swing worker thread? (I don't want to catch the exceptions created by the host application after all)

Question recap:
1. How can I check which threads are started for the function `func` passed into the  `launcher` function and see thier uncaught exception handler?
2. Can I enforce a seperate swing dispatcher for my gui part and the main applications gui part? (If I exitOnClos on a frame of my add in, the third party application closes)?

**Update**:
Considering the anwser from `lbalazscs` I am trying to use the `sun.awt.exception.handler` property, but it has no effect, the exceptions still end up in the log file (applications dfeault behaviour). Am I using it right? (p.s.: I am on Java 1.6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Java 5 or higher, you can also use Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(), which is also described in a newer "Java Specialists' Newsletter":

http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue089.html

And here is the newest Java 7 version:

http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue196.html

Also see this:
[Why bother with setting the "sun.awt.exception.handler" property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794472/why-bother-with-setting-the-sun-awt-exception-handler-property)

EDIT: This is how I use Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (in Java...):

```
public static void setupGlobalExceptionHandling() {
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            handleException(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Since I use java 6 I assume you pointed me in the right direction with . However I have another issue now, I can't get the "sun.awt.exception.handler" porperty to work. I updated the code but it has no effect (see updated question). Since I am trying to catch unhandled exceptions form different threads (including the edt) the `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` seems inappropiate to me.

Comment: With Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler you can set the uncaught exception handling for all threads (is is a static method). See my updated answer.

Comment: thank you very much, this still leaves the property issue (I need to set it I guess), but I don't think it causes any effect (exceptions still pass by my exception handler and run the default way),...

Comment: I would not rely on "sun.awt.exception.handler", because such code won't work in Java 7: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4714232

Comment: the question is not if I want to rely on it (I have the UncaughtExceptionHandler in place) but if I need it. The reason I need it is in your answer: [Why bother with setting the "sun.awt.exception.handler" property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794472/why-bother-with-setting-the-sun-awt-exception-handler-property). I assume that the fact that I don't catch some exceptions (those generated from gui launched code (e.g. buttonclick action)). Unfortunately I am currently forced to use Java 1.6 and can't upgrade to 1.7 easily. And 1.6 users should see the exception too...

Comment: Thanks to your link I got my `solution`: During startup the third party program generates an uncaught exception. Here is a quote from the [bugreport you linked](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4714232): `Another problem with the system property is that it needs to 
be set before the first exception gets thrown. After that, it 
won't have any effect (the handler is cached - for 
performance reasons, I guess).`

Comment: P.P.S.: Actually there was also another problem, forcing me to use the `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`, the swing thread is created by the third party application thus not inheriting the thread group and its exception handler. Thanks again.