# javafx, get a reference to application thread

Tags: javafx-2

In swing we have:

```
boolean SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()
```

that returns true if it is called from swing event dispatch thread.

is there anything similar in javafx?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can check that [you are in the FX thread with](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#isFxApplicationThread%28%29):

```
Platform.isFxApplicationThread();
```

Note that many UI interacting methods will throw an exception when called outside the FX thread.

Comment: +1 for the reference to the docs. I'm studying fx threading to get to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318861/javafx-2-catching-all-runtime-exceptions. I am really uncomfortable with the answers provided there, that mean that in fx you can't even log runtime excepions because you are not able to catch them . Can you give a little help to that question too? :-)