# Java(TM) Platform SE binary error

Tags: java, javafx, crash

I'm currently having a problem with a Java application I'm working on. Randomly, a Java(TM) Platform SE binary error happens when the application closes. It happens when the exit method is called, either directly via or a another method or event, or when I close the application with the window close button.

Problem is, no exception is catched, and I have the following message (developing on Netbeans):
Java Result: -1073741819

And nothing else. I cannot be sure it's an issue with I/O actions, or if something goes wrong with the memory. Since it's a JavaFx application, I do not know how to control the main thread and catch the right exception that would just explain to me what the matter is !

Have you seen that kind of problem before ?

I cannot show you my code due to the number of classes involved. Though, my question is not about solving the problem, just finding a way to identify it.

Thank you very much !

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318861/javafx-2-catching-all-runtime-exceptions ... or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719503/what-to-do-about-uncaught-run-time-exceptions-in-java-fx2

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it does not help. I found this though :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170762/what-does-java-result-means

The number I get is 1073741819, though it does not mean anything to me. I explicetely end my application with the exit method. Even when I close the javafx app, the stop method calls the exit method.

It seems it is linked to an exit code, but I do not understand why the VM crashes and fail to find the source :'(

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue yesterday, First of all, you need to check your driver what you are using is the latest. Secondly, check JDK version is the latest. In my case, I used the latest JDK 17.0.5 and the error has been resolved. Remember that, I use at least version 17.0.5 and above.